# Append to json with node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to append some information to a json response I get. But it doesn't seem like I can push information to the DISPLAY object I get.

The error I get is this.
ReferenceError: DISPLAY is not defined
Trying to push to fbResponse is not working either.

```
readCoin: function(myDB, url, connection) {
    console.log("URL: ", url);
    request(url, (error, response, body)=> {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    var fbResponse = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("Got a response: ", fbResponse);
    //fbResponse[DISPLAY].push({ test: "testinfo"}); Fails here
```

Object information

```
testSetInt.js:9
_id:ObjectID {_bsontype: "ObjectID", id: Buffer(12)}
DISPLAY:Object {BTC: Object, ETH: Object, XRP: Object, …}
 ADA:Object {USD: Object, EUR: Object, SEK: Object}
 BCH:Object {USD: Object, EUR: Object, SEK: Object}
 BTC:Object {USD: Object, EUR: Object, SEK: Object}
```

Comment: Since DISPLAY is not a variable you need single quotes. `fbResponse['DISPLAY'].push({ test: "testinfo"});`

Comment: Your `DISPLAY` show object , so you can't use push method ! I think you can use like `fbResponse[DISPLAY]['test']= "testinfo";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fbResponse[DISPLAY].push({ test: "testinfo"});` will fail because DISPLAY will be interpreted as a variable. Instead wrap DISPLAY in quotes: `fbResponse["DISPLAY"].push({ test: "testinfo"});`.

Or use the simpler syntax:

`fbResponse.DISPLAY.push({ test: "testinfo"})`

If you want to use DISPLAY **as a variable**, you have to define it

`let DISPLAY = "DISPLAY";`

`fbResponse[DISPLAY].push({ test: "testinfo"});`

Comment: This is not working either. Object {RAW: Object, DISPLAY: Object}
testSetInt.js:9
TypeError: fbResponse.DISPLAY.push is not a function

Comment: Ok if DISPLAY is an object, it won't have the push method. You either change the response format from the server to receive an array if you want to use push or use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: isn't this returning the correct object? var fbResponse = JSON.parse(body);

Comment: Yes it does, but you were trying to use push, which is array specific method on an object. So you can either use `Object.assign(fbResponse[DISPLAY], { test: "testinfo"})` or use fbResponse[DISPLAY]['test']= "testinfo";  as suggested @David JorHpan.